# Feature importance calculation for every features to every tree in Random Forest

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I use python library `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier`.
I want to know the feature importance for every feature to all tree. Suppose, I have `P` features and `M` trees.
I want to calculate `PxM` matrix where every feature's feature importance is calculated to every tree.
[Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py#L365) is the source code of sklearn for Random Forest feature importances. In this method, I think `all_importances` variable is PxM matrix. But How can I access that variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get access to the individual trees using [`.estimators_`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) and then call the `feature_importances_`

Here is an example:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5, max_depth=2,
                             random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)

feature_imp_ = [tree.feature_importances_.T for tree in clf.estimators_]
```

output:

```
[array([0.02057642, 0.96636638, 0.        , 0.01305721]),
 array([0.86128406, 0.        , 0.13871594, 0.        ]),
 array([0.00471007, 0.98648234, 0.        , 0.00880759]),
 array([0.02730208, 0.97269792, 0.        , 0.        ]),
 array([0.65919044, 0.34080956, 0.        , 0.        ])]
```